# How to write a PL/SQL Trigger statement inserting into multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting a list of orders back from a remote database.
Here is what a sample of an order looks like:

```
{
"order_number": "58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa",
"order_date": "1/21/2022",
"first_name": "Vinni",
"last_name": "Candey",
"email": "vcandey5@de.vu",
"ip_address": "249.33.234.247",
"credit_card": "372301965255898",
"currency_code": "USD",
"city": "Milwaukee",
"street": "28 Kim Point",
"state": "Wisconsin",
"postal_code": "53210",
"log_data": "",
"lines": [
  {
    "product": "Tomatoes - Roma",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": "$89.21",
    "item_image": null
  },
  {
    "product": "Coffee Swiss Choc Almond",
    "quantity": 6,
    "price": "$162.09",
    "item_image": null
  }
]}
```

I am trying to use a trigger Statement to insert that data into multiple tables such as:
Orders
Customers
Products
Order_Products (bridge table between Orders and Products. columns: Order_number, Product_Id, Quantity)

I asked ChatGbt to make me a PL/SQL trigger to insert into those tables when the data is synched with the table C3_Order_Headers. Here is what it gave me:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_order_data
AFTER INSERT ON orders_data
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  customer_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- Insert customer data into Customers table
  INSERT INTO Customers (first_name, last_name, email, ip_address, credit_card, city, street, state, postal_code)
  VALUES (:new.first_name, :new.last_name, :new.email, :new.ip_address, :new.credit_card, :new.city, :new.street, :new.state, :new.postal_code)
  RETURNING id INTO customer_id;

  -- Insert order data into Orders table
  INSERT INTO Orders (order_number, order_date, customer_id, currency_code)
  VALUES (:new.order_number, TO_DATE(:new.order_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), customer_id, :new.currency_code);

  -- Insert product data into Products table and get product_ids
  DECLARE
    product_id NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..JSON_ARRAYSIZE(:new.lines)
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO Products (name, price, image)
      VALUES (JSON_VALUE(:new.lines[i], '$.product'), SUBSTR(JSON_VALUE(:new.lines[i], '$.price'), 2), JSON_VALUE(:new.lines[i], '$.item_image'))
      RETURNING id INTO product_id;

      -- Insert order product data into Order_Products table
      INSERT INTO Order_Products (order_number, product_id, quantity)
      VALUES (:new.order_number, product_id, JSON_VALUE(:new.lines[i], '$.quantity'));
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

but I am getting this Error:

```
Error at line 18: PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
Error at line 21: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error at line 22: PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
Error at line 17: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_order_data
2. AFTER INSERT ON C3_order_headers
3. FOR EACH ROW
```

Any idea what is wrong with my script? I am trying to loop through the "Lines" column and insert each product into a row in the Products table, then take that newly created Id from the Products table and insert it with the Order_number and quantity in the Order_Products table.

I would like the end result to look like this:

```
 Customers 
 id: (created on insert)
 first_name: "Vinni",
 last_name: "Candey",
 email: "vcandey5@de.vu",
 ip_address: "249.33.234.247",
 credit_card: "372301965255898",
 city: "Milwaukee",
 street: "28 Kim Point",
 state: "Wisconsin",
 postal_code: "53210",
    
    
 Orders:
 order_number:"58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa",
 order_date: "1/21/2022",
 customer_id: (Get that info from the new inserted Customer)
 currency_code: "USD"

Products 
(
  id: (generated on insert)
  name: "Tomatoes - Roma",
  price: "$89.21",
  image: null
)
(
  id: (generated on insert)
  name: "Coffee Swiss Choc Almond",
  price: "$162.09",
  image: null
)

Order_Products:
(
order_number:"58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa",
product_Id: (got from the product that was inserted).
quantity: 1
)
(
order_number:"58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa",
product_Id: (got from the product that was inserted).
quantity: 6
)
```

Comment: "Any idea what is wrong with my script?" Maybe the problem is that you asked ChatGPT to write it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your `orders_data`, `Customers`, `Orders`, `Products` and `Order_Products` tables; the `INSERT` statement you use to insert that JSON; and the expected output for your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders_data (
  data JSON
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
  id    NUMBER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
        PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR2(200)
        UNIQUE
        NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_number VARCHAR2(36),
  order_date   DATE,
  customer_id  NUMBER REFERENCES customers
);

CREATE TABLE order_lines (
  order_number VARCHAR2(36),
  product      VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

Then you can create the trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_order_data
AFTER INSERT ON orders_data
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  customer_id CUSTOMERS.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customers (email)
    SELECT email
    FROM   JSON_TABLE(
             :NEW.data,
             '$'
             COLUMNS (
               email VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.email'
             )
           );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      NULL;
  END;

  SELECT id
  INTO   customer_id
  FROM   customers
  WHERE  email = JSON_VALUE(:NEW.data, '$.email');

  INSERT INTO orders (order_number, order_date, customer_id)
  SELECT order_number,
         TO_DATE(order_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
         customer_id
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           :NEW.data,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             order_number VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.order_number',
             order_date   VARCHAR2(10)  PATH '$.order_date'
           )
         );

  INSERT INTO order_lines (order_number, product)
  SELECT order_number,
         product
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           :NEW.data,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             order_number VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.order_number',
             NESTED PATH '$.lines[*]' COLUMNS (
               product VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '$.product'
             )
           )
         );
END;
/
```

And use the insert:

```
INSERT INTO orders_data (data) VALUES ('{
"order_number": "58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa",
"order_date": "1/21/2022",
"first_name": "Vinni",
"last_name": "Candey",
"email": "vcandey5@de.vu",
"ip_address": "249.33.234.247",
"credit_card": "372301965255898",
"currency_code": "USD",
"city": "Milwaukee",
"street": "28 Kim Point",
"state": "Wisconsin",
"postal_code": "53210",
"log_data": "",
"lines": [
  {
    "product": "Tomatoes - Roma",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": "$89.21",
    "item_image": null
  },
  {
    "product": "Coffee Swiss Choc Almond",
    "quantity": 6,
    "price": "$162.09",
    "item_image": null
  }
]}');
```

Then the `customers` table will contain:

| ID | EMAIL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | vcandey5@de.vu |

And the `orders` table:

| ORDER_NUMBER | ORDER_DATE | CUSTOMER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | 1 |

And the `order_lines` table:

| ORDER_NUMBER | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- |
| 58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa | Tomatoes - Roma |
| 58a01c99-ac60-4f4f-b05e-781714b797aa | Coffee Swiss Choc Almond |

You can amend the trigger to insert extra columns and use the techniques to insert into different tables; this is left as an exercise for you to complete.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mMb3AHAc)

Comment: I have updated what I wanted the end result to be. How can I updated the trigger to get the expected result?

Comment: @Kurtonio This answer shows you a [MRE] of how to do it. You just need to expand it for all the columns and tables.